# Diagonal quadratic form and vector with fixed norm

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have an $n\times 1$ vector $x$ and an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. The diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are all unique and nonzero.

I am interested in the quadratic form associated with $\Lambda$. Formally, the function $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x) = x^T \Lambda x$$

Specifically, if I restrict $x$ so that it lies on the surface $x^T x = \eta$ for some scalar $\eta$, can I make any statements about the quadratic form $f(x)$?

Comment: You can lower-bound and upper-bound it using $\lambda_\min$ and $\lambda_\max$. Other than that - probably no.

Comment: @phil In general, the resulting graph is something called a [Quadric hypersurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Normal_form_of_projective_quadrics). If we know that $\eta > 0$, then the nature of the graph is enough to tell you, at the very least, the signs of the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ (i.e. the signature of the quadratic form).

Comment: @phil More specifically, you could say that the graph is an elliptic ellipsoid, elliptic paraboloid, or a kind of "cylinder" in degenerate cases. If $\eta$ is known, then $\Lambda$ can indeed by recovered from the graph except in the case where $\Lambda$ is empty. If $\eta$ is unknown, then it should still be possible to determine the constants up to a global scaling factor.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you. I have been reading up on quadrics, it is definitely the material I was looking for.